# Quick question: can you describe the direction of motion relative to a particle?

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics

In Gregory R.D.'s *Classical Mechanics*, he has written "Relative to a single particle, the only thing that can be speciﬁed is distance from that particle".

My question is, isn't it possible to describe direction relative to the particle as well? What is the necessity of a rigid body to describe direction?

Comment: I assume he means a single *point* particle.

Comment: Can we not consider the particle as the origin?

Comment: Yes, you can make it the origin. But you have no idea where the $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes are.

Comment: Oh, okay makes sense.. thank you!